# How to secure or disable rpcbind while being an NFS client?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, networking, nfs, internet

I am having a publicly reachable Ubuntu 18.04 LTS server I installed `nfs-common` so that I can mount a remote NFS share for creating backups which is secure and not publicly available. `nfs-common` also installed the `rpcbind` service which is running and apparently needed to mount NFS shares. I have `rpcbind : ALL` in my `/etc/hosts.deny` but I am not confident this is enough to protect `rpcbind` from remote access. It still responds when trying to connect from a remote machine.

I did not find anything useful in particular for this scenario. How can my server act as a NFS client without `rpcbind`? How can I secure `rpcbind` in a way it is fine to run on a publicly reachable server?

Comment: this could be solved in various ways such as appropriate firewall rules to limit NFS traffic to just what is necessary with the NFS server (tcp_wrappers is being deprecated) or to not use NFS for backups and instead use e.g. rsnapshot over SSH

Comment: With the used provider I only have the option of mounting an NFS share or starting another virtual (public) server to create backups.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up blocking the related ports with the default firewall configuration tool [ufw](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UFW) (uncomplicated firewall).